# Honda Insight “check emission system”. Body shake,only 10MPH

Tags: honda

My second generation Honda Insight (2014) suddenly lit the alarm light on the way home yesterday: "check emissions system "Then the car's speed began to drop and the body began to shake. I could not drive, and even smelled bad smell. When I parked the car at the roadside for an hour, I started the car again. Although the body shake still existed, the speed could reach 30mph. However, after driving for about 200m, the speed dropped to 20, and then 10mph. If I stepped on the accelerator deeply, the speed would not increase, and the shaking would increase. Because of the time of the accident For the night, so I drive home very carefully. Do you have any ideas? thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! There are two things which bug me here. First, that it is running rough (obviously). As @motosubatsu states in their answer: Check the codes. Second, why isn't the electric part of the hybrid system kicking in? Was the battery fairly much depleted? Should have been enough to get you down the road.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest you've either lost a coil or a spark plug to the ICE. Until you get the codes from the ECU, you aren't really going to know for sure.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 those would definitely account for the problems with the running - a good clue would be whether the CEL was steady or flashing as the latter would indicate a serious misfire or similar and point towards your hunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to sound strange, but a common cause of this alarm light is the fuel cap not being sufficiently tightened.

Try making sure the cap is tight by turning it until you hear three clicks and see if the problem goes away.

If not you'll need to get the error codes read - there's quite a few different problems that could be the root cause and the codes will give a better idea of where to look.

Comment: With the cap, you probably wouldn't feel a difference in how it runs, would you?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Correct - a loose fuel cap will cause the car to throw a P0442 or P0457 code, but it wouldn't affect the running of the engine.  Definitely some other issue at play here.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  & Chris O Yeah that's bugging me a little - as normally you wouldn't expect it to run rough, but if it's loose enough it could effect fuel system pressure sufficiently or it may have allowed contaminants in. Given it's a quick, easy (and free!) step it's probably worth eliminating it to be sure though.